# Prisma Postres error prepared statement \"s0\" already exists

Tags: postgresql, next.js, orm, server-side-rendering, prisma

I have a Next.js project where I'm using Prisma to read from Postgresql.

I have code like:

```
const rows = await prisma.receipts.findMany({
      where: {
        action_receipts: {
          // https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#filter-on-relations
          signer_account_id: {
            equals: accountName,
          },
        },
      },
      orderBy: {
        included_in_block_timestamp: 'desc',
      },
      take: 2, 
    });
```

I'm often getting errors like:

```
 error: PrismaClientUnknownRequestError: 
  Invalid `prisma.receipts.findMany()` invocation:
  
  
    Error occurred during query execution:
  ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState("42P05"), message: "prepared statement \"s0\" already exists", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("prepare.c"), line: Some(480), routine: Some("StorePreparedStatement") }) }) })
```

(Sometimes instead of "s0" it says something else though, such as "s8".)

What does this mean, and how can I avoid it?

It seems like the problem often goes away if I stop my local server and wait a minute and then start again via `yarn dev` and then try my Prisma query again.  But I'm oblivious to the root cause, which I want to identify and solve.

Comment: Are you using pgbouncer?
I found this issue - https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4752 
This describes error which you are facing.

Comment: @NurulSundarani Thanks. I'd found that issue too, but I've never heard of pgbouncer so doubted that I'm using it. I wonder if it would appear in `yarn.lock`, which I haven't checked yet.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: My intent is always to follow up and write an answer (if I ever learn one) for every question I ask. So I doubt I ever found one for this.

Answer (score 14):

I restarted the project on superbase and it worked.

Go to the settings on the supabase project file and click on `restart project`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was using database pooling (on Supabase) but not including the `directUrl` property in the Prisma schema, like:

```
datasource db {
    provider  = "postgresql"
    url       = env("DATABASE_URL")
    directUrl = env("DIRECT_URL")
 }
```

Everything worked without this until I came to do a migration (when updating a Vercel deployment where changes had been made to the Prisma schema).

In `.env` I added:

```
# PostgreSQL connection string used for migrations
DIRECT_URL="postgres://postgres:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@db.[YOUR-PROJECT-REF].supabase.co:5432/postgres"
```

In addition to:

```
# PostgreSQL connection string with Supavisor config — used by Prisma Client
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres.[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@aws-0-[REGION].pooler.supabase.com:6543/postgres?pgbouncer=true&connection_limit=1"
```

(Obviously Supabase-specific!)

Then I ran `npx prisma db push` locally and redeployed on Vercel (via GitHub) and voila.

(This info was on https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma, although the page seems to have vanished in the last few hours.)