# Prisma Supabase Connection failed Error: Schema engine error: ERROR: prepared statement "s0" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, next.js, prisma, supabase

npm install prisma --save-dev
npx prisma init --datasource-provider postgresql

Setup .env database url from supabase.
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres.pnfqkgzzcnikiuchyljz:g2lIVbri0JazB7eV@aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543/postgres"

npx prisma migrate dev

Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543"

**Error: Schema engine error:
ERROR: prepared statement "s0" does not exist**

Anyone please help on this !

Prisma not connecting to supabase using nextjs14;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prisma Postres error prepared statement \"s0\" already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026259/prisma-postres-error-prepared-statement-s0-already-exists)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring due to the undefined definition of 'directUrl' in the schema.prisma file. You need to follow the instructions in this document: https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma

correct schema.prisma:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl= env("DIRECT_URL")

}
```

You must define "directUrl" too